# Anti-Forgery token usage between MVC pages to classic ASP.NET pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an application which has 80% of it's part in ASP.NET MVC 2. 
I am using Anti-forgery token to avoid Cross-Site Request Forgery.

Say I have an action method -

```
public JsonResult AddMenuFavorite(int id) {
    // code
}
```

which uses the token to prevent CSRF. I have various links in my MVC pages from there I can make a call to this action method smoothly without any error.

While making calls from classic ASP.NET pages, this shows error.

```
Reason:: Anti-forgery token is not embedded in ASP.NET pages it seems.
```

can any one help me with the solution?

Comment: there is no **classic ASP.NET pages** it's called **WebForms**, or **Classic ASP** witch is a scripting language and does not use .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3):

In order to generate the required hidden field containing the token you could use the [`AntiForgery.GetHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547824.aspx) static method:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%= AntiForgery.GetHtml() %>
        <asp:LinkButton 
            runat="server" 
            ID="btn" 
            PostBackUrl="~/SomeController/AddMenuFavorite/123" 
            Text="Go to the MVC site" 
        />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And since your action returns JSON I suspect that you are calling it using an AJAX request. In this case you can use the value of the hidden field generated by the helper to send it along with the AJAX request:

```
$(function() {
    $('#someLink').click(function() {
        $.post(this.href, $('form').serialize(), function(result) {
            // do something with the result
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: with the `on` even there is no need to wrap clicks with DOM ready alike syntax: `$(document).on('click', '#someLink', function() { ... });` :)

Comment: @balexandre, normally I put my scripts at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag so I never use the document.ready anyway. With the `.on` method the reason this works is that it subscribes for changes to the document and when an element with the given id is added it automatically attaches the click event. That's good. It's just that the listening for DOM changes might not be required and I would avoid it if not needed.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - AntiForgery is not being recognized in web forms. I tried to import the namespace System.Web.Helpers even but "Helpers" itself is not being recognized.

Comment: @Ashish, you must add reference to the `System.Web.WebPages` assembly. And the namespace is: `System.Web.Helpers`. But I thought that you was having the 2 in the same ASP.NET application. Isn't this the case? If not you will also have to ensure that the 2 applications have the same machine keys setup or an antiforgery token generated by the WebForms application might not be successfully decrypted by the ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I followed and added reference to assemble and further. But it did not work at all for me. let me know, if you need some more information.